# Getting an error while training data for random forest tree- how can I fix?

Tags: r, random-forest, modeling, training-data

I wrote this code for a random forest model.

```
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(arrow_clean$discountflag, SplitRatio = 0.70)
training_set = subset(arrow_clean, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(arrow_clean, split == FALSE)
length(training_set)
training_set[-3] = scale(training_set[-3])
test_set[-3] = scale(test_set[-3])

head(training_set)

library(randomForest)
classifier = randomForest(x = training_set[-3],
                          y = training_set$discountflag,
                          ntree = 500, random_state = 0)
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-3])
y_pred
cm = table(test_set[, 3], y_pred)
cm
```

It was working but now the following part is giving me an error that says "Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric". How can I fix that for these two lines?

```
training_set[-3] = scale(training_set[-3])
test_set[-3] = scale(test_set[-3])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least one of your predictors is not numeric. When you have a problem related to your data it is advisable to `dput` a sample of your dataset, or post an example that reproduces your error, also include which `library`s do you use. However, probably you have just to convert your predictors. Check the `class` of each column with `str` and then convert the non-numeric predictors with `as.numeric`. Also, is better to use `scale` function before data splitting. See an example with the `iris` dataset

```
set.seed(123)
iris[-5] = scale(iris[-5])
split = caTools::sample.split(iris$Species, SplitRatio = 0.70)
training_set = subset(iris, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(iris, split == FALSE)
library(randomForest)
classifier = randomForest(x = training_set[-5],
                          y = training_set$Species,
                          ntree = 500, random_state = 0)
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-5])
y_pred
cm = table(test_set[, 5], y_pred)
cm
```

This work fine